# Yii scenario not working in module validation

Tags: php, yii

I used the following rules in module:

```
array('password', 'required','on'=>'insert,userchangepassword'),
array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'cpassword','on'=>'userchangepassword'),
array('cpassword', 'required','on'=>'userchangepassword'),
```

> Here I want to use userchangepassword scenario
>
> Its not triggering on userchangepassword action

Here is my controller:

```
$model=new Users('userchangepassword');
if(isset($_POST["Users"]))
{
    //print_r($_POST["Users"]);exit;
    $q = 'UPDATE users SET password = "'.$_POST['Users']["password"].'" 
            where id = "'.Yii::app()->user->getId().'"';
    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($q);
    $cmd->execute();
    $this->redirect(array('users/useraccount'));
}

$this->render('userrest',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

Comment: As @Valentin says: `validate()` is a CModel function. You therefore have to use `$model->validate()` directly or `$model->save()` which calls `validate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign values to model's attributes and call `validate` to validate user input.

```
$model = new Users( 'userchangepassword' );
```

Pay attention, to that fact that you can pass the current scenario in the constructor only if your model is a descendant of CFormModel. Otherwise, you need to call `setScenario` explicitly:

```
$model = new Users();
$model->setScenario( 'userchangepassword' );

if( isset( $_POST["Users"] ) ) {
    $model->setAttributes( $_POST["Users"] );
    if ( $model->validate() ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @pritinarang, right, that means that your validation fails. From your description it's not obvious, what values you submit to your controller. Can you var_dump( $_POST["Users"] )?

Comment: values are in post method its still showing me value  required
array (size=2)
  'password' => string '123' (length=3)
  'cpassword' => string '123' (length=3)

Comment: @pritinarang, just realised that 'require' is a safe validation rule actually. Are you sure that your model extends CFormModel and not CModel?